# When should I feel that my Unit test is complete?

Tags: unit-testing

I've been hit by this lately. When should I feel that my Unit Tests are complete? Namely what's your definition of done when making a Unit test? Can it be the same with Code Coverage (Function coverage, Statement coverage, Branch coverage, Condition coverage)?

You can't test every possible scenario, but given this is a phylosophical question I thought I should post it here.

Comment: When the tests fully validate the known intended functionality of the system.

Comment: Yeah. that's the main idea of a Unit Test. I was more looking in to something like: Step 1) I check this, Step 2) this... , etc...

Comment: Well, “this” in that case would still just be “the functionality of the system”.  It’s not really clear what kind of answer you’re looking for.  There is no one set of tests to validate all or even part of every system.  The tests are just as customized as the code being tested.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to keep in mind that unit-testing is for finding certain types of bugs.  Once you are sufficiently confident that your unit tests catch all these bugs, you are done.  The level of confidence you need can vary depending on the system-under-test, and may even demand other techniques like formal proofs etc.

There are systematic approaches that help you to derive test cases, particularly with the goal to find bugs that are likely to be present, like boundary testing (which helps at finding many of the off-by-errors), or equivalence partitioning.

Coverage analysis can help you to identify run time scenarios (and their corresponding potential bugs) that you have missed - but reaching a certain level of coverage is likely not a helpful goal, for several reasons:

- Not every bug can or should be found with unit-testing.  For example, for memory leaks you rather use a memory checker.  For out-of-bounds accesses you use static analysis or also a memory checker.  For testing interactions with other components or with hardware you rather do integration testing: Code that just deals with interactions should be covered by integration testing, but not necessarily with unit-testing.
- It can be decided that certain bugs are too unlikely to spend your time for creating tests for them.  Keep in mind that you can spend every hour of your time only once, and you should do what has the highest likelyhood of findings bugs.  Thus, running a static analysis and working with the results can be a better use of your time than writing test cases for trivial getters and setters - although this is a simple way to increase test coverage...